# UWP/XAML - Strange white "ribbon" shown in my UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

Recently I'm trying to learn some Windows 10 UWP app developments. And now I encountered a strange issue, where there is a white ribbon in the bottom of my app, see here:

[image: Screenshot #1]

If I drag and enlarge the app window, then there will be another white ribbon on the top, see here:

[image: Screenshot #2]

Here is my XAML for the UI:

```
<Page
x:Class="ApodidaeCore.ClockMainUI"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ApodidaeCore"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid RequestedTheme="Dark" Margin="0,0,0,38" Height="600" Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="439*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="161*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="205*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="819*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="hourTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="191" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" Foreground="White" FontSize="170" Margin="15.2,98,0,0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="clockSymbolTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="141" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=":" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38" Foreground="White" FontSize="105" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="244.2,130,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="minuteTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="197" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218" Foreground="White" FontSize="170" Margin="308.2,98,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="weatherInfoTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="25" Margin="188.2,331,0,0" Text="Unknown" Width="314" Height="33" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="notificationTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="No new notification" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="25" Margin="188.2,369,0,0" Height="30" Width="314" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Image x:Name="weatherInfoIconImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="67.2,321,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Grid.Column="1"/>

</Grid>
```

What should I do to fix this? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

Got fixed, silly me!

I've wrongly set the grid height and the margin.

Remove those two variables will fix that issue.

Change this:

```
<Grid RequestedTheme="Dark" Margin="0,0,0,38" Height="600" Background="Black">
```

to this:

```
<Grid RequestedTheme="Dark" Background="Black">
```

Comment: glad you came back to explain